# Random image in a table view

Tags: java, android, tableview

I have a TableView with 4 parts of the field. which in every field filled images A, B, C and D. You can see in the image below :

[image]

My question is how do I make the image appear randomly when the activity start ? Like this one :

[image]

Thanks for the questions !

Answer (score 2):

You can always use the static random-method in the Math-class and then create a switch structure

```
 int square = ((int)(Math.random() * 4) + 1);


 switch (square) {
    case 1:
      // .. code
     break;
    case 2:
     // .. code
     break;
    case 3:
     // .. code
     break;
    case 4:
     // .. code
     break;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
int min = 1;

int max = 4;

Random r = new Random();

int i = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;

switch(i) {
case 0:
      // .. code
     break;
    case 1:
     // .. code
     break;
    case 2:
     // .. code
     break;
    case 3:
     // .. code
     break;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many logics... Pseudocode of the one, I can think of right now is as follow:

- Step 1: Save image resource info (path) in HashMap with key as 0 to 3.
- Step 2: Generate Math.random() between 0 and 3
- Step 3: Fetch the image from HashMap with the number got in step 2.
- Step 4: Show it in the table.

Hope this helps. All the best.